# ffmpeg extract lossless png frame

Tags: image, ffmpeg, png, image-compression

To extract lossless frame, I just run the command below. The frame looks different from frame shown in video.

```
ffmpeg -i xx.mp4 -f image2 %06d.png
```

Video showed in ffplay (same timestamp was sought):

[frame1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJozM.jpg)

Png frame:

[frame2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEucK.jpg)

Comment: have you tried using bmp instead of png?